# Failed to restart containerd.service: Unit not found

Tags: kubernetes, containerd

I have installed containerd 1.5.4 by following below steps in CentOS 7.9:

```
wget -c https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/download/v1.5.4/containerd-1.5.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf containerd-1.5.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /
mkdir -p /etc/containerd
containerd config default > /etc/containerd/config.toml
```

I have followed the docs from [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) and also created the config according to them. But when I try to start containerd:

```
[root@iZuf62lgwih3vksz3640gnZ sysctl.d]# systemctl start containerd
Failed to start containerd.service: Unit not found.
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue is that you are only copying binary files, you are not creating any systemd service.

Be careful when using `-C /` flag with the `tar` command. On my CentOS 7 machine, two first commands:

```
wget -c https://github.com/containerd/containerd/releases/download/v1.5.4/containerd-1.5.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf containerd-1.5.4-linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /
```

led to overwrite the `/bin` directory which destroyed the OS.

Back to the question, it seems like you are mixing two different instructions for installing `containerd` package. The [instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) from official Kubernetes wiki that you mentioned in your question are pretty-forward and good to follow. Try them:

Step 1. Install the containerd.io package from the official Docker repositories:

```
yum install -y yum-utils
yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
yum install -y containerd.io
```

Step 2. Configure containerd:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/containerd
containerd config default | sudo tee /etc/containerd/config.toml
```

Step 3. Restart containerd:

```
systemctl restart containerd
```